# how to track session in mobile apps using cordova

Tags: cordova

I am developing an app like WhatsApp or something else here after all the authentication process finished and closes the app and re-entering in to that app that should track the session and process the further update I am using Intel xdk for developing Cordova app how should I don't want routines because it confuses so I want clear set of code any body please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track the user session

```
document.addEventListener("pause", userOffline, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", userOnline, false);

function userOnline(){
    //user is online Do ur stuff
}
function userOffline(){
    //user is offline Do ur stuff
}
```

Hope it will helps you.